# Wordpress JS CSS combination not working and I do not know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a page in wordpress twenty seventeen theme.

On the top of the page, I have created a bar for users to toggle font size and background colour.
[See Image for Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOnmH.png)

My code for the above are as follows:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Change Background</td>
   <td><img id="button_colour_yellow" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2080" src="Colour-FFFFDB.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></td>
   <td><img id="button_colour_red" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2079" src="Colour-FFCCFF.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></td>
   <td><img id="button_colour_blue" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2078" src="Colour-E6FFFF.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></td>
   <td><img id="button_colour_green" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2077" src="Colour-CCFFCC.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></td>
   <td><img id="button_colour_black" class="size-full wp-image-2076" src="Colour-000000.png" alt="Colour 000000" width="28" height="28" /></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

To toggle the background colour, I have have some CSS stylesheets

```
Background_Black{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;   
}

Background_Yellow
{
    background-color: #ffffdb;
    color: black; 
}

Background_Green
{
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    color: black; 
}

Background_Red
{
    background-color: #ffccff;
    color: black; 
}

Background_Blue
{
    background-color: #e6ffff;
    color: black; 
}
```

You get the idea. I want to toggle the colour bar, so that when someone click on the image, the colour will switch.

So I add the JS script to the JS folder in my wordpress.

```
$("button_colour_black").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("Background_Black");
});

$("button_colour_green").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("Background_Green");
});

$("button_colour_blue").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("Background_Blue");
});

$("button_colour_red").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("Background_Red");
});

$("button_colour_yellow").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("Background_Yellow");
});
```

The thing is, when I click on the images, nothing happens. :(

Please, I am not a good programmer, and is new to js script and I have no idea what is wrong with my code. Any help is so much appreciated.

I did check similar posts, and they indicated this should work. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Check your browser console for any javascript errors first.

Comment: and the status of this question is.......... ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't take this the wrong way but try to first tackle some basic exercises to get you familiar with how CSS classes and jQuery selectors work, here is an example to get you started.

```js
$("[id^=button_colour_]").click(function(){
    $('#test-area').attr('class', $(this).data('color'));
});
```

```css
.Background_Black{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;   
}

.Background_Yellow
{
    background-color: #ffffdb;
    color: black; 
}

.Background_Green
{
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    color: black; 
}

.Background_Red
{
    background-color: #ffccff;
    color: black; 
}

.Background_Blue
{
    background-color: #e6ffff;
    color: black; 
}

.test-area{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Change Background</td>
<td><img id="button_colour_yellow" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2080" src="Colour-FFFFDB.png" alt="Colour-FFFFDB" width="28" height="28" data-color="Background_Yellow"/></td>
<td><img id="button_colour_red" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2079" src="Colour-FFCCFF.png" alt="Colour-FFCCFF" width="28" height="28" data-color="Background_Red"/></td>
<td><img id="button_colour_blue" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2078" src="Colour-E6FFFF.png" alt="Colour-E6FFFF" width="28" height="28" data-color="Background_Blue"/></td>
<td><img id="button_colour_green" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2077" src="Colour-CCFFCC.png" alt="Colour-CCFFCC" width="28" height="28" data-color="Background_Green"/></td>
<td><img id="button_colour_black" class="size-full wp-image-2076" src="Colour-000000.png" alt="Colour 000000" width="28" height="28" data-color="Background_Black" /></td>
<td></td>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="test-area">TEST AREA</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to define the classes with a period before the name like this in your stylesheet.

```
.Background_Green
{
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    color: black; 
}
```

Also with your jQuery selector it's missing the hash symbol for the element id before the image names.

```
$("#button_colour_black").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("Background_Black");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew Schultz wrote, you need to define CSS rules for classes with a preceding dot and your jQuery selection of an ID element needs to include the `#` symbol.

Additionally, you obviously you want to switch the background color and font sizes for the *whole page* (not for the clicked button), so your jQuery shouldn't address `this`, but either the `html` or the `body` element - depending where you defined your initial background color and font size. So if this was done for `body`, your jQuery needs to be approximately like this:

```
$("#button_colour_black").click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("Background_Black");
});
```

(and similar for the other buttons)

note: The HTML code you posted was missing the closing `</tr>` code - I added that in an edit.